# Fresh Ubuntu Server installation gave very little disk space to root

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Could someone tell me what I did wrong? I've installed Ubuntu Server probably 20 times already on different computers without issues. Last time I did it on a new server with a 240GiB SSD as its bootup disk, with default settings and guided/recommended partitioning/LVM on an empty disk as usual, I ended up with this:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         126G   12K  126G   1% /dev
tmpfs                         26G  1.5M   26G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/gaston--vg-root  9.1G  3.8G  4.9G  44% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         126G  4.0K  126G   1% /run/shm
none                         100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M   39M  185M  18% /boot
/dev/mapper/gaston--vg-home  202G  3.2G  189G   2% /home
```

Why does my filesystem mounted on `/` have only 9.1GiB allocated to it? Looks like LVM gave all my space to `/home` and `/run`. I didn't even notice that at first, and now, I keep running out of space on `/`. I might reinstall, and if I don't know how to solve this by then, I'm just going to disable LVM.

Comment: For now, I've moved `tmp` into `home/tmp` and symlinked it because Spark was putting stuff into `tmp` and exhausting the root's disk space.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion at this stage of my exploration of Ubuntu is to see if you can run Ubuntu Live from CD, get GParted installed, and try to increase the size of the / partition. As always, back up before you try it!

Comment: I do have GParted installed, but GParted can't edit LVM volumes AFAIK. It just sees one partition, `/dev/sda1`, which contains all LVM volumes. I tried poking around in `system-config-lvm`, and it seems like I would be able to resize it if there were some free space in the LVM partition, but there isn't. My only option would be to remove `home`, expand `root`, then re-add `home` after.

Comment: You know, since `home` just has user data in it (i.e. a few git clones), maybe I could do it. But I risk messing something else up since I don't really understand LVM... never saw the point in having logical volumes if I already have a partition table.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I wonder if you could add "home2," copy all user data to the new home 2, then delete home, and rename home2 to home?

Comment: Good point. I could shrink `run`, create `home2` in the new free space, copy `home` to `home2`, then rename. Also, no need for apologies :)